# Clicking a JavaScript link on website

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel

I am trying through VBA to generate automatically a report from my bank's website.

I managed to reach the website and plug in my user id and password without any problem. I've reached the page where I can normally generate the report.
Now I have to simulate a click on the link... But I can't manage to do it.

Here is a screenshot of the website, with the HTML code of the link I have to click on to generate the report (Summary Report Copy).

[image: screenshot]

Here is the HTML code of the link I need to click on:

```
<a id="irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus" href="#"  style="float:left;" title="Summary Report Copy" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'if(isDateValidForMassPayPD()==\'false\' &amp; isWareHouseRptPD(\'23\') ==\'true\'){RichFaces.$(\'irCustomStepOne:panelWareHouseRptError\').show(event, {\'top\':\'100px\', \'left\':\'300px\'});return false;}else{if(!onReportLink(\'23\')) return false;}','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'irCustomStepOne\'),{\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus\':\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus\',\'repId\':\'3368127\',\'dayTypeKey\':\'PREVIOUS_DAY\',\'userAction\':\'Run\'},\'_blank\')');return false" class="">Summary Report Copy</a>
```

I've tried this line of VBA code, but doesn't work:

> IE.Document.getElementById("irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus").FireEvent "onclick"

How can I click on this "Summary Report Copy" thanks to VBA?

Here is the complete HTML code of the part of the webpage where the link is located. Maybe I am not using the right ID?

```
 <td width="290px">
 <span id="irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportNmGrp">
 <a id="irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus" href="#" style="float:left;" title="Summary Report Copy" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'if(isDateValidForMassPayPD()==\'false\' &amp; isWareHouseRptPD(\'23\') ==\'true\'){RichFaces.$(\'irCustomStepOne:panelWareHouseRptError\').show(event, {\'top\':\'100px\', \'left\':\'300px\'});return false;}else{if(!onReportLink(\'23\')) return false;}','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'irCustomStepOne\'),{\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus\':\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus\',\'repId\':\'3368127\',\'dayTypeKey\':\'PREVIOUS_DAY\',\'userAction\':\'Run\'},\'_blank\')');return false">Summary Report Copy</a>
 <a id="irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamePrint" href="#" style="float:left;display:none;" title="Summary Report Copy" onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'if (!onReportLink(\'23\')) return false;','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'irCustomStepOne\'),{\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamePrint\':\'irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamePrint\',\'repId\':\'3368127\',\'dayTypeKey\':\'PREVIOUS_DAY\',\'userAction\':\'Print\'},\'_blank\')');return false">Summary Report Copy</a>
 <span id="irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:rpId" style="float:left;display:none;">3368127</span>
 </span>
 </td>
```

Comment: Did you tried `IE.Document.getElementById("irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestatus").click`?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, but I get :
        Run Time Error '424'
        Object Required
Which i don't understand since this is the Id of the link...

Comment: Try to wait few seconds after navigating to the website, looks like the document isn't completely loaded. Add this above the link click line: `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:08"))`

Comment: Same thing, I had already put this line of code to be sure that everything is loaded. Sorry for wasting your time I should have told you before ;-)
Any other idea to trigger this link ?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to wait for the page to be fully loaded. Something like

```
Do: VBA.DoEvents: Loop While IE.Busy ' wait for the page to load
Dim el 'As IHTMLElement
Set el = IE.Document.getElementById("irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestat‌​us")
If el Is Nothing Then el = IE.Document.querySelector("a[title='Summary Report Copy']")
If el Is Nothing Then MsgBox("Link not found!") : Exit Sub
el.click
Do: VBA.DoEvents: Loop While IE.Busy ' wait for next page to load
```

Comment: Hello Slai, thanks a lot for your help. Your code gives me a "Run Time Error '424' Object Required". I am going to paste the complete html code, so that we can better understand the structure of the website.
Maybe I am trying to click on the wrong link ??

Comment: In Tools > References... check "Microsoft Internet Controls" and "Microsoft HTML Object Library". Then you need something like `Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer`

Answer (score 0):

This always worked for me. Try it please:

```
For each lnk in IE.Document.getElementByTagName("a") 
If lnk.ID = "irCustomStepOne:headerDataTableId:23:reportnamestat‌​us" Then
    lnk.Click
    Exit For
Next
```

Comment: This also gives me the "Run Time Error '424' Object Required".
I am going to paste the complete html code, so that we can better understand the structure of the website.